# how to exclude a directory in find

Tags: unix, find

I have ready many posts on this, and tried them all, but none work of have any effect on the find output what so ever.

I have basically a bunch of source files, but the way grails works, it puts a "target" directory in one of the sub folders with all the build artifacts which we want to exclude.

My basic command line which includes the files I need is as follows:

```
 find * -type f -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp" -print > ha
```

Note I am not using "find ." as I dont want "./xxx" to appear in the output.

I am getting "myapp/target/xxx/yyy" in ha.

I have tried all the following, and none have any affect on the output:

```
 find * ! -path "backoffice/target/"  -type f -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp" -prune -print > ha
 find * \( ! -path "backoffice/target/*" \)  -type f -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp" > ha
 find * -type f -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp" -not -path '*/target/*' > ha
 find * -type f -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp" ! -path "*target*" > ha
 find * -type d \( ! -wholename "backoffice/target/*" \)  -type f -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp"  -print > ha
 find * ! -wholename "backoffice/target/*"  -type f -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp"  -print > ha
```

and many variations of the above.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find * -path "backoffice/target/" -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp" \) -print
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer, 99% of posted solutions to "excluding a sub-directory" seem to not work (for me at least).

Interestingly, this is our attempt to get the list of source files for a grails project:

```
  find * -type d \( -name "target" -o -name "test" \) -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.groovy" -o -name "*.gsp" -o -name "*.java" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js" -o -name "*.less" -o -name "*.properties" -o -name "*.sql" -o -name "*.xml" \) -print > ha
```